# Matlab: multiply subset of three dimensional array with two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a AxBxC array where AXB are pointing to individual grids of a field that i sampled (like coordinates) and C corresponds to the layers underneath. Now I want to calculate the impact of certain activities on these individual points by multiplying it with a 2D matrix.
E.g.

```
x=5; %x-Dimensions of the sampled area
y=5; %y-Dimensions of the sampled area
z=3; %z-number of layers sampled
Area= zeros(x,y,z);
AreaN= zeros(x,y,z);
```

now I want to multiply every layer of a given point in X*Y with:

```
AppA=[0.4,0.4,0.2;0.4,0.5,0.1;0.1,0.2,0.7];
```

I tried:

```
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
AreaN(i,j,:)= AppA*Area(i,j,:);
    end
end
```

Unfotunately I get the error:

```
Error using  * 
Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.
```

Any help to this is appreciated since I am not yet really familiar with matlab.

Comment: is your `z` the same length of `AppA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct Approach**

I think, to correct your code, you need to convert that `Area(i,j,:)` to a column vector, which you can do with `squeeze`. Thus, the correct loop-based code would look something like this -

```
AreaN= zeros(x,y,z);
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        AreaN(i,j,:)= AppA*squeeze(Area(i,j,:));
    end
end
```

---

Now, there are efficient no-loop/vectorized approaches that can be suggested here to get to the output.

**Vectorized Approach #1**

First approach could be with matrix multiplication and has to be pretty efficient one -

```
AreaN = reshape(reshape(Area,x*y,z)*AppA.',x,y,z)
```

**Vectorized Approach #2**

Second one with **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** -

```
AreaN = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,Area,permute(AppA,[3 4 2 1])),3))
```

**Vectorized Approach #2 Rev 1**

If you would like to get rid of the `squeeze` in the `bsxfun` code, you need to use an extra `permute` in there -

```
AreaN = sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(Area,[1 2 4 3]),permute(AppA,[4 3 1 2])),4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will go with you Vectorized Approach #1

Comment: @user2386786 Agreed on that, it has to be the fastest of the lot!

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the matrix multiplication problem:

```
AreaN(i,j,:)= AppA*reshape(Area(i,j,:),3,[]);
```

You might want to consider using `bsxfun` to aviod loops.